# command line syntax that will show MySQL details

Tags: 12.04, mysql

Is there a command-line syntax that will show details about my installed MySQL (eg. ports, config file paths, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server System Variables**

- To see the values that a server will use based on its compiled-in defaults and any option files that it reads, use this command:

  ```
  mysqld --verbose --help
  ```
- To see the values that a server will use based on its compiled-in defaults, ignoring the settings in any option files, use this command:

  ```
  mysqld --no-defaults --verbose --help
  ```
- Inside MySQL `SHOW VARIABLES` will show the current settings MySQL is using. [Here is a list of variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-variables.html).
- Inside MySQL `status` will show information about the install (collation, threads, slow queries and more).

---

Besides that you can also have a look at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. That file is used to store settings. It holds the port, pid file location, socket etc. Example showing the port number:

```
more /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep port
port            = 3306
port            = 3306
```